# Using Beamer, condensed outertheme with proper colors

Tags: beamer, color

I am condensing a few of my talks in Beamer. The theme I like creates an enormous header when I have many sections

```
 \usetheme{Malmoe}
 \usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
```

[image: exampleofmanysections]

I like the CambridgeUS theme, but I can't get the Brown color scheme when I try something like this

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
```

the red colors from Cambridge override my selection. Is there an easy way to have this color theme with a header that looks like this?

```
[ section ]      [ subsection ]
(white on black) (white on brown)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading the `CambridgeUS` theme, load the themes that are used in the definition of `CambridgeUS`, but replace the `beaver` complete color theme with the `whale` outer color theme plus your definition of the `structure` color theme.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,usennames}]{beamer}

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
% \usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=white}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure} 

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\section{bar}

\subsection{subbar}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{A block}
(Block content)
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]